# how not insert double records with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, null

I'm trying to find a way to insert a new record only if it doesn't exist in the table.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
USE [ABSTest]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_InsertBudgetCommessaInPreventivo]    Script     Date: 01/07/2013 09:12:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Alex Ziani>
-- Create date: <04/01/2013>
-- Description: <Insert di valori con inserimento di parametri>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertBudgetCommessaInPreventivo] 
@Progressivo                    nvarchar(50),
@Durata                         float,
@Costo                          money,
@CostoStandard                  money,
@Tariffa                        money,
@SpeseStandard                  money,
@Codice_Tipo                    nvarchar(50),
@Codice_FiguraProfessionale     nvarchar(10),
@Codice_Risorsa                 nvarchar(50),
@Codice_Commessa                nvarchar(20),
@Codice_ODL                     nvarchar(30),
@Task                           nvarchar(100)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS   (SELECT * FROM Preventivo WHERE Progressivo = @Progressivo 
            AND Quantita = @Durata 
            AND Costo = @Costo  
            AND CostoStandard = @CostoStandard 
            AND Tariffa = @Tariffa 
            AND SpeseStandard = @SpeseStandard 
            AND FkCodiceEnumTipoPreventivo = @Codice_Tipo 
            AND FkCodiceEnumFiguraProfessionale = @Codice_FiguraProfessionale
            AND FKCodiceRisorsa = @Codice_Risorsa 
            AND FkCodiceCommessa = @Codice_Commessa 
            AND FkCodiceOrdineDiLavoro = @Codice_ODL
            AND Task = @Task)               
BEGIN           
    INSERT INTO [ABSTest].[dbo].[Preventivo]
           ([Progressivo] 
           ,[Quantita] 
           ,[Costo]
           ,[CostoStandard]
           ,[Tariffa]
           ,[SpeseStandard]
           ,[FkCodiceEnumTipoPreventivo]
           ,[FkCodiceEnumFiguraProfessionale]
           ,[FKCodiceRisorsa]
           ,[FkCodiceCommessa]
           ,[FkCodiceOrdineDiLavoro]
           ,[Task])
     VALUES
           (@Progressivo
           ,@Durata
           ,@Costo
           ,@CostoStandard 
           ,@Tariffa
           ,@SpeseStandard 
           ,@Codice_Tipo 
           ,@Codice_FiguraProfessionale
           ,@Codice_Risorsa 
           ,@Codice_Commessa 
           ,@Codice_ODL
           ,@Task)
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
    RAISERROR 50001 'ERRORE: RECORD GIà PRESENTE'
 END
END
```

This works fine, but all the values (except the primary key) are `Nullable`, so if i put as parameters `Null` values, it doesn't work. How can I engineer it work with `Null`s aswell?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code for checking it:

```
IF NOT EXISTS   (SELECT * FROM Preventivo WHERE ISNULL(Progressivo,'') = ISNULL(@Progressivo,'') 
        AND ISNULL(Quantita,0) = ISNULL(@Durata,0) 
        AND ISNULL(Costo,0) = ISNULL(@Costo,0)
        AND ISNULL(CostoStandard,0) = ISNULL(@CostoStandard,0)
        AND ISNULL(Tariffa,0) = ISNULL(@Tariffa,0)
        AND ISNULL(SpeseStandard,0) = ISNULL(@SpeseStandard,0)
        AND ISNULL(FkCodiceEnumTipoPreventivo,'') = ISNULL(@Codice_Tipo,'')
        AND ISNULL(FkCodiceEnumFiguraProfessionale,'') = ISNULL(@Codice_FiguraProfessionale,'')
        AND ISNULL(FKCodiceRisorsa,'') = ISNULL(@Codice_Risorsa,'') 
        AND ISNULL(FkCodiceCommessa,'') = ISNULL(@Codice_Commessa,'')
        AND ISNULL(FkCodiceOrdineDiLavoro,'') = ISNULL(@Codice_ODL,'')
        AND ISNULL(Task,'') = ISNULL(@Task,'') )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ISNULL as the comparison operator. Might slow down a bit

```
SELECT * FROM Preventivo WHERE ISNULL(Progressivo, '') = ISNULL(@Progressivo, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using Case statement

For eg

```
AND Quantita = CASE @Durata
WHEN null THEN Quantita
ELSE @Durata
```

So when @Durata==null case will return column Quantita  itself so the result will be true (Quantita  =Quantita  )

Answer (score 0):

for null you need to put conditon

```
where column_name  is null
```

in your cause you can make use of `IsNull()` function available in sql server like this

```
 where IsNull(column_name,-1) = Isnull(@variable,-1)
```

compare value of variable with column as given above resolve the issue easily

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is trying to do

```
NULL = NULL
```

Change the first statement of the Stored Procedure and it should work

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
```

If you are using SQL 2008 R2 or above, please consider using MERGE statements.

Raj